# How to quantify correlation between two non-Gaussian AR(1) time-series?

Tags: distributions, correlation, autoregressive, cross-correlation

I am trying to understand the need for lateral transshipment within the same echelons in our supply-chain. Lateral transshipment would be more helpful if the stock-levels at two stocking-points are not highly correlated. The stock at stocking-point, in our case, can be approximated by a *non-gaussian stationary AR(1) timeseries*.

I understand that for a gaussian AR(1), I could use Pearson R. Are there similar ways to quantify correlation in non-gaussian scenarios?

I am new to both stats.stackexchange.com as well as to time-series modelling (I am primarily a data engineer); so pardon any deficiency in my understanding of the concept or in the question. If you need any further information on the problem, please do comment and tell me about it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Correlation is well defined for a wide variety of distributions, not only Gaussian.

Comment: @RichardHardy I understand that correlation is defined for many distributions. My question is more about how do you measure that correlation in case of other distributions. Am I right in saying that PearsonR is a reasonable measure of correlation only in case of normal distributions? If yes, are there similar measures I can use to understand correlations in case of non-normal distributions?

Comment: Pearson R is the definition correlation and therefore it is the only reasonable measure of the object it defines. If you want to measure something else than correlation, use some other measure.